# using method 'mysql_native_password' failed

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013

An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I need to connect my database to the report viewer in visual studios however this error always appears and i dont know what changes i have to make...the password was already set to 'root' however this error still appears, I want to know what "(password: NO)" means since this only appeared when i accidentally flushed out the privaleges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password NO just means that you don't pass over a password. 
Are you connecting like this:

```
string connsqlstring = "SERVER=" + server + ";PORT=" + port + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";database=" + databank;
sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(connsqlstring);

            sqlconn.Open();
```

Or how are you doing it ?
Another thing is, i had problems before with Root and made a new User with which i now connect.
Maybe that helps.

Cheers,

Frozen :)

Comment: She wrote:"  I want to know what "(password: NO)" ", i answered that so yeah it was a answer. Other than that, i had the same Problems and this was my solution to deal with the Problem. Such comments are not necessary, when someone just wants to help